# SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow doesn't throw but not data is inserted

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get familiar with Android and its database API.
I've created a class that inherits from SQLiteOpenHelper and this
is how I create the table in the database

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    try {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + FUELS_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + "_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "DATE_OF_FUELS DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,"
                + "SELLER_POSITION TEXT DEFAULT 'unknown',"
                + "AMOUNT REAL"
                + ");"
        );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DATABASE_NAME, e.toString());
    }
}
```

The function used to add data to the DB is the following implemeneted within
the same class is

```
public void addNewFuel(float amount) {

    // Create the content to insert into the database
    ContentValues newEntry = new ContentValues();
    newEntry.put("amount", amount);

    // Get database handler
    try {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DATABASE_NAME, e.toString());
        return;
    }

    // Begin transaction and insert data
    long returnedValue;
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        returnedValue = db.insertOrThrow(FUELS_TABLE_NAME, null, newEntry);
        Log.v(DATABASE_NAME, "return value " + returnedValue);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DATABASE_NAME, e.toString());
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    db.close();
}
```

but apparently no data is added. The returnValue is always 1. The method doesn't throw,
and when I pull out the DB with adb and look at it's content is totally empty.

I just can't understand what I'm missing.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks,
S

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**See benritz's answer for the correct solution. This answer is incorrect, but I'm unfortunately not able to delete it since it's an accepted post.**

/******* *NOT CORRECT!!*

Since you're inheriting from SQLiteOpenHelper, your call to `getWritableDatabase()` already starts a DB transaction. From the [SQLiteOpenHelper API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html):

> Transactions are used to make sure the
>   database is always in a sensible
>   state.

Thus you don't need to call `db.beginTransaction()` and `db.endTransaction()`. Those extraneous transaction calls are messing up your inserts. I plugged the same scenario into my project and found that the same index (6 in my case), was returned when using those transaction methods. When I remove the calls I get my desired results (multiple records inserted).

*NOT CORRECT!!* *******/

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works. I'm really wondering how does call mess things up, and why the insert doesn't throw. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I think an exception isn't thrown because there's nothing particularly wrong with your insert statement, and you're not violating any table constraints, etc. Instead things are getting mixed up in the multiple transaction calls. I'll have to do some more research to see why the nested transaction behaves the way it does. I understand why it would not insert anything, but the fact that an id is returned at all is odd.

Comment: This is really odd! The source code for SQLiteOpenHelper certainly doesn't open any transactions except for database creation and update. So after the getWriteableDatabase() call returns, no transactions are active for the database! Either something really screwy is up, or this answer is bogus.

Answer (score 29):

McStretch's answer is incorrect. `getWritableDatabase()` does not create a transaction for your code, the quoted line from the docs is referring to transactions being used for the onCreate and onUpgrade methods meaning that you don't need to add transaction code in those methods. You still need add transaction code for any other method that requires transactions.

emitrax's code is not working correctly as `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` is not being called which means the transaction will be rollbacked by `db.endTransaction()`.

Comment: Well this makes a lot more sense